# Is the call order guaranteed for multiple SetWindowSubclass against the same window?

Tags: windows, winapi, subclassing, comctl32

I am using `SetWindowSubclass` to set up two different subclass procedures against a control (in this case, a multiline edit field).

One subclass "edit" functionality specific to edit controls and the other "base" functionality specific to any control. It seems that no matter what order I apply these in "base" is being called before "edit".

Has anyone else hit this issue?

Comment: How is the API to know which window procedure you deem "base" and therefore always call that first?

Comment: Hi Cody - my understanding is that the most recently added subclass is called first, going backwards to the first subclass. However, the docs on MSDN say nothing on this. I may end up just having a single level of subclassing and have each control-specifc class call the 'base' logic itself. Gotta love win32. :)

Comment: I couldn't dig up any information about this. As you say, the logical behavior would be last subclassed is the outer one. This blog post hints at just zthis happening: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2003/11/11/55653.aspx

Comment: Hi Peter - thanks for your input. Looks like it's time for me to pester Raymond Chen at next PDC. He has helped me with other murky win32 issues.

Answer (score 2):

There is no guarantee of order, sorry.